# SSH password storage

Tags: ssh, passwords, workflow, scheduler, rundeck

How does the structure of the file where you store your ssh password looks like (keys/path/rundeck.password)?

10:37:39 OPNsense1  Failed to read SSH Password stored at path: keys/rundeck.password: org.rundeck.storage.api.StorageException: Path does not exist: keys/rundeck.password

10:37:39   Failed: ConfigurationFailure: Failed to read SSH Password stored at path: keys/rundeck.password

Why do I get this error?

10:37:39 SRV2012LAB  Execution failed: 16 in project project: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [OPNsense1: ConfigurationFailure: Failed to read SSH Password stored at path: keys/rundeck.password + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, Node failures: {OPNsense1=[ConfigurationFailure: Failed to read SSH Password stored at path: keys/rundeck.password + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, status: failed]

Answer (score 1):

Rundeck need be configured before you start using key storage. The key storage can be DB or file system.

The key can be added from Rundeck UI by click project config -> Key Storage
[image]

Read more on [Key Storage backends](http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/key-storage.html#storage-backends)